# Autosize columns slightly larger in spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I have consistently used the `Columns.AutoFit` function in VBA.

Is there any way to make it effectively "Autofit to 105% size?"

I know I can loop through the columns to do this and just set each size to its current size times 1.05, but this seems like a poor way to do this.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible.  I was going to recommend your last sentence based on the title as the best way to do this.

Comment: @Byron I added that as an answer (which is how I am currently doing this, it's just ugly)

Comment: Unfortunately, you often have to settle for ugly in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it with column iteration:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 6
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(i).ColumnWidth = _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(i).ColumnWidth * 1.05
    Next i
```

Note that you need to use `ColumnWidth` vs `Width` if you use this sort of strategy.

Comment: You could probably get away with iterating through the `UsedRange` : `For Each rng_col in UsedRange.Columns / rng_col.ColumnWidth = rng_col.ColumnWidth * 1.05 / Next rng_col`.

Comment: @Byron I've had way, way, way too many issues with `UsedRange` over my life - it too easily misses areas (if you have a blank column) etc.

Comment: Never seen it come up short, but I have been burned by it including "extra" cells with stray formatting.